# SQL Insert query for identity column in H2 database

Tags: h2

I have the following DDL in a H2 database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER 
(
    USER_ID IDENTITY,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
);
```

While trying the below DML, I'm unable to create rows. I couldn't find a way to insert data into the `IDENTITY` column.

```
INSERT INTO USER (USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD) 
VALUES ('Anand', 'Anand$');
```

> NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
>   INSERT INTO USER (USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD) VALUES ('Anand', 'Anand$') [23502-197] 23502/23502

Comment: I'm not huge on SQL...but don't you need a primary key defined in the table? Initially I was going to say it's because it's the primary key, which cannot be null, but I see you don't define a primary key anywhere. Not sure if this is some variant of SQL where this is not required. I've always had to explicitly define a primary key.

Comment: Works for me. What is your h2 version? Does it work if you define it as `user_id integer generated always as identity`?